# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PROTOTYPE Struts2.5

Tags: java, prototype, struts2-interceptors

I recently migrated my project from **Struts 2.3 to Struts 2.5.**
All was working fine in UAT.
When I moved the same to production, I ma getting below error.
The project deploys successfully, then when I hit a Struts action, this error pops up for the action and all the resources on the jsp page.
PFB stacktrace of one of them, all errors are same, only difference is they are caused while accessing different resources: like css, js,  and actions.
On the browser I am getting **500 error.**

```
2017-06-05 16:46:50,945 INFO  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] (default task-7) Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
2017-06-05 16:46:50,950 INFO  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] (default task-7) Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
2017-06-05 16:46:50,956 INFO  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] (default task-7) Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
2017-06-05 16:46:50,962 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-7) UT005023: Exception handling request to /SmsPayTransaction/images/hdfc_logo.png: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PROTOTYPE
    at org.apache.struts2.config.DefaultBeanSelectionProvider.register(DefaultBeanSelectionProvider.java:389)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:226)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:906)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:111)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:97)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.createFilter(ManagedFilter.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.getFilter(ManagedFilter.java:66)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using Wildfly 10 & **Struts library version  is 2.5.10.1**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try find a class `Scope` in your project? Looks like a problem with your classpath (same library with multiple version?).

Comment: Thank you @kucing-terbang
I looked for Scope.class and found it in one of the other jar files.
Those jar files were pertaining to Struts2.3. <br> Scope is a enumeration used in Struts, version 2.3 did not have the value PROTOTYPE in it

Comment: @kucing_terbang your comment really made to look at things and that really helped. Thanks for saving time.